# How can I send an email when someone uses the HTML download Attribute?

Tags: pages

I am using this code (screenshot) to enable someone to download a file from my webpage:
[image]

Is there a way to also trigger an email and have it sent when someone clicks on the download button?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to set the href URL to instead point to a PHP file that first sends the email you want, and then triggers a [force download](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/forcing-file-downloads-in-php) of the image file path that you specify.

Alternatively you could set an `onclick` event to the link to execute Javascript to AJAX via `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=` and then hook a function to the AJAX action in WordPress. There are many tutorials on available on how to add AJAX actions, but basically (where `image_email` is the `action` variable set in your AJAX call.):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_image_email', 'custom_email_function'); // for logged out users
add_action('wp_ajax_image_email', 'custom_email_function'); // for logged in users
function custom_email_function() {
    // send email code
}
```